# sorting an array in the same order as another one

Tags: javascript, arrays

My problem is that I have two arrays to be sorted in the same order.

They are as follows:

```
objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
zorder = [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

I need to order the `zorder`, so that it is **1, 2, 3, 4,**,that's quite easy, but I need the objects to be sorted the same way, like so:

```
objects = [obj1, obj4, obj2, obj3]
zorder = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers are working for me. All the answers I found would turn it into this:

```
objects = [{name:obj1, order:1}, 
           {name:obj2, order:3},
           {name:obj3, order:4},
           {name:obj4, order:2}]
```

and then sort it from there. I **cannot** do that because the `objects` array needs to stay exactly the same except for the order, the same is true for `zorder`. I can create a new array but then I have the same problem from the start.

I'm really stuck on this and I would be very grateful for your help, thank you in advance.

Edit:
the objects array contains 4 objects.

Comment: `because the objects array needs to stay exactly the same except for the order` Do you mean that reassignment (or extracting into a new variable) is not an option?

Comment: What are obj1, obj2, obj3, and so on? Strings?

Comment: the object array is full of objects

Comment: How do you identify objects using the values within the array `zorder`?

Comment: also yes reassignment isn't an option, the objects can only exist inside the original array or the rest of my code begins to break.

Comment: their place in the array, objects[0] has the number of zorder[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Map of the objects using the zorder values as keys before sorting zorder.

Then Array#sort() zorder and  Array#map sorted array returning the associated object from the Map object

```js
let objects = [{id:100}, {id:300}, {id:400}, {id:200}],
zorder = [1, 3, 4, 2],
map = zorder.reduce((a, c, i) => a.set(c, objects[i]), new Map);

zorder.sort((a, b) => a - b);

objects = zorder.map(n => map.get(n));

console.log('zorder', zorder)
console.log('objects', objects)
```

Comment: yes that works well but do the id's just go into my already existing objects, and also do the id's have to be in the same order as the zorder to begin with. otherwise thank you very much.

Comment: I only used `id` to  give a visual to match zorder. What is actually in each object is totally irrelevant but the new order will be correct

Comment: Notice that I never reference the `id` property anywhere

Comment: how would i differentiate the 2 if their z order is the same, for example {id:100}, {id:100} and 1, 1 - at the moment it overrides the second one with the first one regardless, do i have to add an if statement to prevent it or is there a way to do it within the existing code

Comment: I assumed that the `zorder` was all incremental and unique as in the example in question. If there are duplicates that complicates this a bit

Comment: So would need the Map to hold arrays of objects for each zorder, then flatten those arrays at the end

Comment: Are there properties with unique values in the objects?

Comment: no but i can easily implement an id  into the object

Comment: That would help. Then map object of `{id,zorder}` to use for sorting

Comment: could you please show me how this would work, I've been trying to do it for a while now but with no success. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Can you create a set of example data in jsfiddle or other sandbox site that I can test against